# Can I power a raspberry pi and motor hat from the same source?

Tags: power, alternative-power, dc-motor

I have a raspberry pi 3 and an [Adafruit motor hat](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2348). The motor hat is powered from a 24v wall plug adapter while the pi is powered from a 5v one. I'd like to save a wall outlet and cleanup the wires (and save some energy?). Is here a simple way to use one wall outlet to power both boards?

I'm not looking for solutions like power strips or dual outlets, I'm asking about a single compact power supply with 5 and 24v outputs, or a circuit to convert 5v to 24v or 24v to 5v.

Comment: use a power bar

Comment: You need to clarify your question. It is possible to use a module to convert 24V to 5V

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is OK format. 
OK, little different story now., It depends how comfortable you are with hardware. 
I have not ask Mrs  Google for “dual voltage power supply”. You can "convert" 24V to 5V using venerable 7905 regulator, BUT going from 24V to 5V@ 1 to 2 A will require a good heat sink and 7905 is designed to supply 1.5A. I am sure there are others which can provide more steady current.

The other issue is – motors have surge current and depending on your  24V power supply , if used as common source, you need to make sure such surge will no affect the 5V supply derived from 24 V.

Actually you energy consumption would be greater since “drop” from 24V to 5V will generate heat.
Take a look at Rpi 3B “power chip” design /schematic. Maybe you can find “open source / module” using it. Not sure if it can handle 24V DC input

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No.
I was tempted to edit you post to use better terminology, but I won't do that. 
Technically you can use DUAL outlet or single to dual adapter to plug your power supplies into. 
Mechanically - only you can answer that - I have no idea how your power supplies look and if they will fit together into dual outlet. .(Please do not post their pictures!)

**No, you will not save ANY energy**.

Comment: I'd welcome an edit - my vocab's pretty bad. I'm not looking for solutions like power strips or dual outlets, I'm asking about a single compact power supply with 5 and 24v outputs, or a circuit to convert 5v to 24v or 24v to 5v.